# Do any Chinese languages or dialects contain a rolled/trilled R?

Tags: pronunciation, topolect, accent

From 20:00 to 22:00 of this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnMeISMY6eM), the speaker appears to pronounce the R sound with standard Mandarin pronunciation in 若 and 仍然. However, he rolls the R in 肉. He also taps his R in 人, but not as strongly. He doesn't pronounce the R at all in 而. For context, he from Malaysia and he says something in Cantonese later on in the video.

Do any native Chinese speakers of any dialect roll/trill their R's, or would this be interference from a non-Chinese language?

Comment: check this video, Hubei dialect has the trilled R: https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV16u411d7or/?share_source=copy_web&vd_source=92658e7a2d6c7e6ff79bb494adaadff5&t=41

Answer (score 1):

According to [this map](https://phoible.org/parameters/5D1D7FB69E1A3C0C60001FBC0C19ED87#2/50.3/139.6) there are some Chinese languages in which the trill *r* is present.

Answer (score 1):

1. The rolled R sound exists only in a couple of Hubei Mandarin varieties where 子 is pronounced as [ r̩ ].
2. There are no rolled Rs in Malaysian Chinese varieties. There might be some Malay influence but the Malay r is usually a flap one or a postalveolar approximant.